# Mysql Query, group by Year then by tag

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a table with services like:

```
invoice number
servicename
amount
price
tag (consultingfee, education fee, travel expense etc..)
date
```

I would like to make a query that groups by Year and then groups by tag.

I would like to get a result like following:

```
Year ------------ Tag -------------- Tag --------------- etc ....
2015 ----------- Consulting fee -- Education fee --- etc..
2014 ----------- Consulting fee -- Education fee --- etc..
```

I hope you get what i want.

Updated with Mysql structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `serv` (
  `Id` int(25) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Invoicenumber` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `service` text NOT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `price` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `Done` varchar(25) NOT NULL default 'false',
  `rabattchoice` varchar(10) NOT NULL default 'false',
  `support` varchar(11) NOT NULL default 'false',
  `DateServ` date default NULL,
  `ServTag` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'false',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3946 ;
```

Data

```
INSERT INTO `serv` 
(`Id`, `Invoicenumber`, `service`, `ammount`, `price`, `Done`, `rabattchoice`, `support`, `DateServ`, `ServTag`) VALUES
(113, '31991', 'Kursavgift -> name', '1', '8250', 'true', 'false', 'false', '2005-09-12', 'EXTERN'),
(114, '31992', 'Kursavgift -> Name', '1', '8250', 'true', 'false', 'false', '2005-09-12', 'EXTERN');
```

Thank you guys for helping. I solved it by making a query for each tag and then i putt the data in multiple tables with float left. But this created another problem! Surprise!!

Comment: Maybe is that what you want (Group Concat): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Could you please provide piece of data (sample), above mentioned table contains

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName GROUP BY YEAR(date), tag;
```

i hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sub query to group by year first, then I would group by tag and use group_concat() with DISTINCT to gather all unique tags in one column :

```
SELECT t.year, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag)

FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Table AS t

    GROUP BY t.year
) AS t

GROUP BY t.tag
```